# Check the check box in a table

Tags: ruby, capybara

In my application I have check any one of the check box and click on save button. I used with table as follows to select the option, but it doesnt work:

```
# with in table, set 
within_table('countryTable') do
    find(:xpath, "//tbody/tr/td[1]/checkbox").set(true)
end 

click_button('Save')
```

but its not working.....

Select countries for this owner

```
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxAU' name='AU' value='AU' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        Australia
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxCA' name='CA' value='CA' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        Canada
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxFR' name='FR' value='FR' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        France
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxGG' name='GG' value='GG' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        Guernsey
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxJP' name='JP' value='JP' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        Japan
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxNZ' name='NZ' value='NZ' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        New Zealand
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxZA' name='ZA' value='ZA' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        South Africa
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxCH' name='CH' value='CH' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        Switzerland
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxAE' name='AE' value='AE' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        United Arab Emirates
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxGB' name='GB' value='GB' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        United Kingdom
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class='first'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' id='CheckboxUS' name='US' value='US' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        United States
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reach the check box by id, css, or xpath.

```
# to check the FR with xpath
find(:xpath, "//input[@name='FR']").click()

# to check the FR with id
find(:id, "CheckboxFR").click()

# to check the FR with css
find(:css, "#CheckboxFR").click()
```

if you want to use within_table which narrow the scope:

```
within_table(find(:id, "table_id")) do 
    find(:id, "id_of_option").click()
end
```

Comment: Thank you for needed help. I will keep you posted, if i stuck in my code.

Comment: For whatever reason, the check method and your examples just don't work. I'm not sure why because the unique id does exist and there are no duplicates.

Comment: @chaostheory did you run Ramesh case and not passed? any errors please give it?

Comment: @MesutGüneş No, I'm running this against my own html, which seems straightforward. What's even stranger is that the results aren't consistent. Sometimes capybara finds the element. Sometimes it doesn't. Based on the debug file that capybara generates, the html that capybara is seeing is consistent with what we expect. I'll probably make a separate post with details soon.

Comment: UPDATE: I solved my issue. In certain cases with heavy javascript, I have to wait a second or more for the page to fully load before I do anything.